# Translating the following high level code into MIPS Assembly code

Tags: mips

I have translated this C program into MIPS assembly code.
So, here I want to know:

1. Have I done something wrong?
2. If my assembly code is correct, can I do it more precisely by reducing the
   number of instructions. I have used 14 instructions here

Here is my approach for converting this C program
This is my MIPS assembly code

#s0 = res

```
main:
    addi $a0 , $0 , 27
    addi $a1 , $0 , 3
    jal division            # call function 
    add $s0 , $v0 , $0      # res = returned value



division:
    addi $t0 , $0 , 0       # $t0 = 0
    addi $s0 , $0 , 0       # $s0 = val and val = 0
    add $s1 , $0 , $a0      # $s1 = i   and i = 27
    
loop:
    slt $t1 , $s1 , $t0      # checking if i>0
    bne $t1 , $0 , break     # if $t1 = 0 then break
    addi $s0 , $s0 , 1       # else val = val + 1
    sub $s1 , $s1 , $a1      # i = i - y
    add $v0 , $s0 , $0       # put return value in $v0
    j loop

break:
     jr $ra                  # return to caller
```

This is the high level C program

```
int main(){

    int res;
    res = division (27, 3);

}

 int division(int x, int y)
{
    int i;
    int val = 0;
    for (i = x; i>0; i = i-y){
        val = val + 1;
    }

    return val;
}
```

Comment: _"Have I done something wrong?"_ Sounds like something you could test yourself, using a simulator like SPIM or MARS.

Comment: Single step and see if it does what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errors:

The relation is negated incorrectly.  You have translated it as

```
for ( i = x; i >= 0; i -= y )
```

So, it will loop one time more than you want (when the integer division is exact).  You are aware that loop condition test requires negation for the if-goto-label style of assembly:

```
if ( ! (i > 0) ) goto break;
```

However `! (i > 0)` is `i <= 0` where you have `i < 0`.

You don't properly terminate the program when the `main` is finished, so it will accidentally fall into the divide subroutine.  The solution is to add an exit syscall to the `main`.

---

Suggestions:

The register usage is excessive, and using fewer registers will also decrease the number of instructions required.  Further, using the `$s` registers without preserving their original values is a violation of the calling convention.  However, the best solution is to simply avoid using them in that function — just use `$a0` and `$a1` directly instead of copying them elsewhere.

(It is ok to use `s` registers in `main` without preserving their original values, b/c `main` is at the top of the call chain — it has no caller — by contrast we might consider `division` as a general purpose function that could be called from any caller, and so should follow the calling convention.)

We not only want to minimize the instructions, but also the number of instructions in the loop.  You're doing the work of "return val" by copying `$s0` into `$v0`, but every time in the loop whereas only once is necessary, so that is better left for after the loop.  Even better still, simply use `$v0` for the counter (`val`) in the first place.

The `slt` instruction has an equivalent `slti` that is handy when comparing to a constant.  With `slti`, no need to load a constant `0` into `$t0` register.  If you did need a constant 0 in a register, there is always the `$0` register as well.

The MIPS instruction set has relational branch instructions that compare with zero, so you can branch on register <= 0 (or < 0) directly without `slt`/`slti`.

Comment: Hi, @Erik Can we  solve this error `for ( i = x; i >= 0; i -= y )` just using **slt** here?

Comment: Yes.  MIPS doesn't have a `sle` as a direct instruction (some assemblers will expand that), but there's two other ways to reverse / negate things: one tool is to swap the operands of `slt`, and, the other is to negate / reverse the branch (branch on false vs. branch on true) beq .. $0 intstead of bne ... $0.  Between the two approaches we can achieve any relational operator.

Comment: So, for example, a <= b is the same as ! (a > b), which is the same as ! (b < a).  The b < a can be done with `slt $t0, b, a`; but now we need to branch on false, so we follow with `beq $t0, $0, label`.   Hopefully you get the idea.